# Querying 64-bit numbers in MongoDB with javascript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, 64-bit

I have a mongodb document with an array that contains both normal numbers (32-bit) and 
big ones (64-bits), and I query this document with the node javascript driver for mongodb.

When querying the document in a mongo shell, I can see 64-bit numbers printed as NumberLong.  For example: `NumberLong("1099511627776")`

Basically I have two questions:

(1) Is there a clean way to check if a value is a 64-bit number?  Today I use the following expression which is by elimination

```
if (typeof counters[slot] !== "number") {
    // I assume counters[slot] is a 64-bit object
}
```

(2) How do I cast this value to an instance of `mongo.Long`?  Today I cast to mongo.Long in a convoluted way.  Is there a cleaner way to perform the cast?

```
var mongoLong = require('mongodb').Long;
if (typeof counters[slot] !== "number") {
    var bigNumber = mongoLong(counters[slot].low_, counters[slot].high_);
    // do things with bigNumber
}
```

Thanks!

Note: 
One may wonder why I need to cast a Long to a Long.
The reason is because the "Long" value which was
returned by the MongoDB javascript driver query is **not really an instance of the Long class**.  i.e.
it wasn't created with a Long() constructor, i.e. you cannot invoke the member functions on it, like getHighBits(), or isNegative().

Answer (score 0):

Okay. There are a couple of ways you can get numbers stored as different BSON types in MongoDB. For starters let's consider this information in the shell first:

```
db.numbers.insert({ "n": NumberLong(1) })      // 64bit
db.numbers.insert({ "n": NumberInt(1) })       // 32bit
db.numbers.insert({ "n": 1 })                  // Actually a Double!
```

All have difference BSON types as shown, so the best way to query for each is using the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator which tests for that field "type":

```
db.numbers.find({ "n": { "$type": 18 } })      // 64bit
db.numbers.find({ "n": { "$type": 16 } })      // 32bit
db.numbers.find({ "n": { "$type": 1 } })       // Double
```

If you tried to do this with JavaScript evaluation, then only the last two respond to your current test, and it's not the 64bit result since the "typeof" would just return object:

```
db.numbers.find(function() { return typeof(this.n) == "number" })
db.numbers.find(function() { return typeof(this.n) == "object" })
```

So only the last test matches the 64Bit integer since that is how this evaluates in JavaScript. But really the above `$type` test is better since it can be used directly in the query and use native code. Native code is better than JavaScript evaluation either inside or outside the query, so it is best to use it. And it's faster.

If you have a whole bunch to convert then you are going to need to loop the collection, covert to Long and write back. And best way to construct is using [`Long.fromInt`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html#long-fromint), as well as of course handling the loop with Bulk Write Operations:

```
var async = require('async'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Long = require('mongodb').Long;


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  db.collection('numbers',function(err,collection) {

    var bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    var count = 0;

    var stream = collection.find(
      {
        "$or": [
          { "n": { "$type": 16 } },
          { "n": { "$type": 1 } }
        ]
      }
    ).stream();

    stream.on('data',function(data) {
      bulk.find({ "_id": data._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "n": Long.fromInt( data.n ) }
      });

      if ( count % 1000 == 0 )  {
        stream.pause();
        bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
          stream.resume();
        });
      }

    });

    stream.on('end',function() {
      if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
        bulk.execute(function(err,result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        });
      console.log("done");
      process.exit();
    });

  });

});
```

That's just a basic premise working example, but it's the best way to go through your whole collection and covert the types as wanted.

Comment: It's a good idea, and I might do this.  But it doesn't actually answer my question.  I'm not interested in changing the query.  Inside each document, there are multiple values.  So I need to loop over the values inside the document, and determine the type of each value.  Also, there is question (2).

Comment: @GaryWeiss Well question two was how to cast, so that is shown, use Long.fromInt. If you are not sure which fields contain the values you want to convert then just forgo the query and inspect the elements to see if they match your condition. Is that a problem that you need help with for (1)?

Comment: For question one, I guess I was hoping for a function called Long.isLong(x).  For question two, the value returned is an object which looks like this: ({ _bsontype: 'Long', low_: -1342987186, high_: 147890796 }) but it is NOT really a Long yet because I cannot call the Long functions (e.g. and()).  So how do I cast that to a bona-fide Long ? using fromInt won't work (unless I missed something?).  I guess I am looking for Long.fromObj(x)

Comment: @GaryWeiss Why are you looking for "is Long"? Don't you want the complete opposite? I thought you are looking to convert numbers that are not long. For (2) The third time I'm saying it now. You use Long.fromInt(). Converting a 64bit to 32bit does not make any sense since there is likely an overflow. So I'm really stumped at what you are saying and what is not answered.

Comment: I am not interested in *converting* anything.  I don't know why you think that.  I simply have a document which I retrieved from MongoDB, which contains an array.  Some of the values inside the array are 32-bit, and some are 64-bit, and that's just fine.  Now given a index in the array, I want to test if the value happens to be a 64-bit, and if so, then I want to *cast* it to a mongo.Long and work with it.

Comment: @GaryWeiss So do your current test or fix your query or whatever and use the method I've told you "four" times now to cast it properly. You question however seems to point to "looking for longs" and then trying to cast them as a Long ??? It's already a long so you don't need to cast it. If you want to operate on non-Long values with Long values then you need to cast the other as a Long. Don't comment back on the comment. Explain your question better and then tell me. Your question does not read like that and the reason there is this long stream of comments is you have not explained yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60528/discussion-between-gary-weiss-and-neil-lunn).